# Entity Framework: how to specify a nonclustered index for model

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Good day. I want to specify nonclustered index for increase search speed for this table:

```
create table Staff(
    Id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    FirstName nvarchar(50) not null,
    LastName nvarchar(50) not null,
    Position nvarchar(50) not null
);
```

So, i have executed this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX StaffIdx
    ON Staff(FirstName, LastName, Position);
```

And now i have several questions:

1. I have correct understand that created index will increase speed of search in my case?
2. Is it necessary to specify this index for EF model or it will be used automatically?
3. If i should to mark index as separated field (or something else), how it should looks?
4. What query will be use created index?

1) `Select * from Staff;`

2) `Select FirstName from Staff;`

3) `Select FirstName, LastName from Staff;`

4) `Select LastName, Position from Staff;`

5) All above

Comment: None of those queries are "searches", because there are no `where` clauses. There's not much you can do to speed up "give me every record in the table".

Comment: @Blorgbeard okay, thanks. But where created index can be useful?

Comment: You created the index without any idea why you were doing it?

Comment: Here, read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/